# right side black space

Tags: html, css

I am actually trying for mobile responsive but whenever I am trying for less than 639px then the right side black screen is coming and the black space goes on increasing as I reduce the screen size but I don't want that space I want my screen should look full and proper. The whole code I have written by using framework work tailwind CSS
[doubt Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ros.png)

I have tried to add some styles to the body like going for

```
<body class="w-full h-full m-0 p-0 overflow-x-hidden">
```

I have got this solution from stack overflow but still not working please tell me how to avoid that black space on the right-hand side

```
<body class="bg-zinc-900 w-full h-full m-0 p-0 overflow-x-hidden">
  <!--Navbar Section Starts-->
  <section area="navbar-section" class="text-white">
    <nav class="max-w-7xl mx-auto flex justify-between">
      <div class="flex items-center shrink-0 sm:ml-4">
        <div><img src="./images/icons8-visual-studio-code-2019-240.png" alt="" class="h-10 mr-12"></div>
        <div class="text-lg -ml-8">Visual Studio Code</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex items-center text-zinc-400 font-semibold -ml-44 sm:invisible md:invisible lg:visible min-[320px]:invisible max-[639px]:invisible">
        <ul class="flex gap-5">
          <li class="hover:text-white">Docs</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">Update</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">Blog</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">Api</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">Extensions</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">FAQ</li>
          <li class="hover:text-white">Learn</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-end md:invisible lg:visible sm:invisible min-[320px]:invisible max-[639px]:invisible">
        <div class="flex bg-neutral-700 py-4 px-12 hover:bg-zinc-600">
          <img src="./images/search.svg" alt="" class="h-4 mr-2 mt-1 cursor-pointer">
          <div>Search Docs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex bg-blue-600 items-center py-4 px-8 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-700">
            <img src="./images/download.svg" alt="" class="h-4">
          <div>Download</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <!--Navbar Section Ends-->
  
  <!--Banner Section Start-->
  <section area="banner">
    <div class="text-center bg-neutral-800 py-2 min-[320px]:w-full max-[639px]:w-full">
        <span class="text-sky-300 cursor-pointer hover:underline">Version 1.75</span>
        <span class="text-white">is now available! Read about the new features and fixes from January.</span>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Banner Section Ends-->

  <!--Main area starts-->
  <section area="main-area">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto flex flex-col gap-y-8 items-center justify-between my-12 px-2 md:flex-col lg:flex-row">

      <div class="mb-0 h-1/2">
        <p class="text-5xl text-white text-center mb-2 font-thin">Code Editting.</p>
        <p class="text-5xl text-white text-center mb-2">Redefined.</p>
        <p class="text-white text-center my-4 text-zinc-500 text-lg">Free. Built on open source. Runs everywhere</p>
        <div class=" flex text-center justify-center text-white gap-1 my-4">
          <button class="text-lg font-bold bg-blue-600 p-3 px-6">Download For Windows
            <p class="text-sm font-light">Stable Build</p>
          </button>
          <button class="text-lg font-bold bg-blue-600 p-3">
            <img src="./images/white-arrow-png-41944.png" alt="" class="h-5">
          </button>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center bg-zinc-800 text-zinc-700 py-2 rounded-lg mb-4"><span class="hover:underline text-sky-700 cursor-pointer">Web</span>, 
          <span class="hover:underline text-sky-700 cursor-pointer">Insiders edition</span>, <span class="text-zinc-400">or</span> <span  class="hover:underline text-sky-700 cursor-pointer">other platforms</span></p>
        <p class="text-center text-zinc-500 text-xs">By using VS Code, you agree to its</p>
        <p class="text-center text-sky-700 text-xs">license and privacy statement.</p>
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="./images/VisualStudio Image.png" alt="" class="h-4/5 w-4/5 ml-40 md:mx-auto sm:mx-auto min-[320px]:mx-auto max-[639px]:mx-auto">
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Main Area Ends-->

  <!--Features Section Starts-->
  <div class="bg-white">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto grid grid-cols-2 py-4 md:grid-cols-4 py-4 gap-y-6 lg:grid-cols-4 place-items-stretch py-2">
      <div class="text-center hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-white hover:border-2">
        <img src="./images/light icon.png" alt="" class="m-auto md:h-14 sm:h-12">
        <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-lg">IntelliSense</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-2">
        <img src="./images/rundebug icon.png" alt="" class="m-auto md:h-14 sm:h-12">
        <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-lg">Run and Debug</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-2">
        <img src="./images/builtin git.png" alt="" class="m-auto md:h-14 sm:h-12">
        <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-lg">Built-in-Git</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center hover:cursor-pointer hover:border-2">
        <img src="./images/extension icons.png" alt="" class="m-auto md:h-14 sm:h-12">
        <h1 class="text-2xl md:text-lg">Extension</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Features Area Ends-->
  
  <!--Our Customers Section Starts-->
  <div class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 px-10 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-2 py-32">
      <div class="flex">
        <img src="./images/Customer Image One.jpg" alt="" class="h-20 rounded-full mr-2">
        <div><p class="text-sm font-bold hover:text-sky-700">Una Kravets<span class="font-medium text-zinc-400 text-xs ml-1 hover:cursor-pointer">@Una</span></p>
          VS <span class="text-sky-700 hover:cursor-pointer">@code</span> does so many things right. I’m constantly impressed by the UX, and customizing workspace / user preferences is no exception.  It just keeps getting better ❤️</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <img src="./images/Customer Image Two.jpg" alt="" class="h-20 rounded-full mr-2">
        <div><p class="text-sm font-bold hover:text-sky-700">Jonathan Dunlap<span class="font-medium text-zinc-400 text-xs ml-1 hover:cursor-pointer">@jadbox</span></p>
          VS Code will have deep remote development. You can connect to a container running a different OS and use any VS Code plugins, linting, debugging for that environment. </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex">
        <img src="/images/Customer Image Three.jpg" alt="" class="h-20 rounded-full mr-2">
        <div><p class="text-sm font-bold hover:text-sky-700">Pavithra Kodmad<span class="font-medium text-zinc-400 text-xs ml-1 hover:cursor-pointer">@PKodmad</span></p>
          VS Code is my most used and favorite editor. I love being able to customize the editor - changing the layout, the icons, fonts and color scheme is so easy!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Our Customers Section Ends-->

  <!--Features Section Part Two-->
  <section area="features-section">
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-16 px-5">
        <div class="flex justify-around sm:flex-col md:flex-row lg:flex-row min-[320px]:flex-col max-[639px]:flex-col">
            <img src="/images/image Two.svg" alt="" class="mr-32 sm:mx-auto md:h-40 lg:h-60 md:mr-24">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-3xl mb-8 sm:">Meet IntelliSense.</p>
            <p class="leading-10 sm:leading-8">Go beyond syntax highlighting and autocomplete with IntelliSense, which provides smart completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-20 px-5">
        <div class="flex justify-around sm:flex-col sm:flex-col-reverse md:flex-row min-[320px]:flex-col max-[639px]:flex-col">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-3xl font-light mb-4">Print statement debugging is a thing of the past.</p>
            <p class="leading-10">Debug code right from the editor. Launch or attach to your running apps and debug with break points, call stacks, and an interactive console.</p>
          </div>
          <img src="./images/imageThree.svg" alt="" class="sm:mx-auto md:h-40 lg:h-60 md:ml-24">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-20 px-5">
        <div class="flex justify-around sm:flex-col md:flex-row min-[320px]:flex-col max-[639px]:flex-col">
          <img src="./images/imageFour.svg" alt="" class="mx-auto md:h-40 lg:h-60 mr-24">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-3xl font-light mb-4">Git commands built-in.</p>
            <p class="leading-10 -8">Working with Git and other SCM providers has never been easier. Review diffs, stage files, and make commits right from the editor. Push and pull from any hosted SCM service.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-20 px-5">
        <div class="flex justify-around sm:flex-col sm:flex-col-reverse md:flex-row min-[320px]:flex-col max-[639px]:flex-col">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-3xl font-light mb-4">Extensible and customizable.</p>
            <p class="leading-10">Want even more features? Install extensions to add new languages, themes, debuggers, and to connect to additional services. Extensions run in separate  processes, ensuring they won't slow down your editor. Learn more about extensions.</p>
          </div>
          <img src="./images/Hundreds-of-Extensions.png" alt="" class="h-56 sm:mx-auto order-1 mb-8 md:h-40 lg:h-60 md:ml-24">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto py-20 px-5">
        <div class="flex justify-around sm:flex-col md:flex-row min-[320px]:flex-col max-[639px]:flex-col">
          <img src="/images/imageSix.svg" alt="" class="mr-32 sm:mx-auto md:h-40 lg:h-60 md:mr-24">
          <div class="">
            <p class="text-3xl mb-8">Deploy with confidence and ease</p>
            <p class="leading-10">With <span class="text-sky-600 hover:cursor-pointer hover:underline">Microsoft Azure</span> you can deploy and host your React, Angular, Vue, Node,
              Python (and more!) sites, store and query relational and document based data,
              and scale with serverless computing, all with ease, <span class="text-sky-600 hover:underline">all from within VS Code.</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Features Section Part Two Ends-->

  <!--Programming Icon Section-->
  <div class="bg-gray-100 mx-auto grid md:grid-row-2 lg:grid-row-2 py-20">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto grid sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-4 gap-y-6 gap-x-16 lg:grid-cols-6 px-20 gap-y-6 gap-x-16 mb-8  min-[320px]:grid-cols-2">
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/program icon One.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">Javascript</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/program icon two.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">Python</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/program icon threee.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">Java</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/markdown.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">Markdown</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/typescript.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">TypeScript</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/cpp.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">C/C++</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/json.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">JSON</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/powershell.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">Powercell</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/html.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">HTML/CSS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/csharp.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">C#</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/php.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">PHP</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/yaml.svg" alt="">
          <p class="text-lg">YAML</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-center my-6 text-lg text-cyan-700 hover:underline">and many more languages on the Marketplace...</p>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
      <button class="bg-blue-600 text-white py-4 px-10 text-lg font-semibold">Get Started Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Programming Icon Section Ends-->

  <!--Requirements Section Starts-->

  <section area="downloadSection" class="bg-white py-12">

  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-x-12">

    <div class="text-white w-84">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center mb-5 ">
        <img src="./images/windows-icon-png-5802.png" alt="" class="h-32">
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-blue-600 w-60 py-3 mb-5 sm:mx-auto hover:bg-blue-700 hover:cursor-pointer">
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/download (1).svg" alt="" class="h-4 mt-1 mr-2">
          <p>Windows</p>
        </div>
        <div>Windows 8,10,11</div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
        <div class="text-black font-semibold">
          <p>User Installer</p>
          <p>System Installer</p>
          <p>.zip</p>
          <p>CLI</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col mb-5">
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x86</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x86</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x86</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x86</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-white w-84">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center mb-5 ">
        <img src="./images/linux (2).png" alt="" class="h-32">
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center  w-60 py-3 mb-5 sm:mx-auto">
        <div class="flex gap-2">

         <div class="containerOne flex flex-col bg-blue-600 px-8 py-3 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:cursor-pointer">
          <div class="flex">
            <img src="./images/download (1).svg" alt="" class="h-4 mt-1 mr-2">
            <p>.deb</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex">
            <p>Debian</p>
            <p>Ubuntu</p>
          </div>
         </div>

         <div class="conteinerTwo flex-col bg-blue-600 px-8 py-3 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:cursor-pointer">
          <div class="flex">
            <img src="./images/download (1).svg" alt="" class="h-4 mt-1 mr-2">
            <p>.deb</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex">
            <p>Debian</p>
            <p>Ubuntu</p>
          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
        <div class="text-black font-semibold">
          <p>.deb</p>
          <p>.rpm</p>
          <p>.tar.gz</p>
          <p>Snap</p>
        </div>

        <div class="flex flex-col mb-5">
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm32</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm32</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">x64</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm32</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Arm64</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs">Snap Store</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="text-white w-84">
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center mb-5 ">
        <img src="./images/apple-logo.png" alt="" class="h-32">
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-blue-600 w-60 py-3 mb-5 sm:mx-auto hover:bg-blue-700">
        <div class="flex">
          <img src="./images/download (1).svg" alt="" class="h-4 mt-1 mr-2">
          <p>Mac</p>
        </div>
        <div>macOS 10.11+</div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
        <div class="text-black font-semibold">
          <p class="mb-4">.zip</p>
          <p>CLI</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col mb-5">
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs mb-4 hover:bg-blue-700">Intel Chip</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs mb-4 hover:bg-blue-700">Apple Silicon</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs mb-4 hover:bg-blue-700">Universal</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row gap-0.5 mb-1">
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Intel Chip</p>
            <p class="bg-blue-600 ml-0.5 p-0.5 text-xs hover:bg-blue-700">Apple Silicon</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </section>

  <!--Requirements Section Ends-->

  <!--License Section Starts-->
    <section area="licensePage" class="bg-gray-100 py-16">
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-2 mb-20 sm:grid-cols-1">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center sm:mb-10">
          <p class="text-2xl font-semibold">What's new feature sonner</p>
          <p class="text-lg">Get the <span class="text-sky-700 hover:cursor-pointer">Insiders build</span> instead.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
          <p class="text-2xl font-semibold">Use <span class="text-sky-700">vscode.dev </span>for quick edits online!</p>
          <p>GitHub, Azure Repos, and local files.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto text-center">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <p class="font-semibold mb-10 text-zinc-600">License and Privacy Terms</p>
          <p class="mx-40 leading-10 text-zinc-600 sm:mx-32">
            By downloading and using Visual Studio Code, you agree to the <span class="text-sky-700">license terms</span> and <span class="text-sky-700">privacy</span> statement. VS Code automatically sends telemetry data and crash dumps to help us improve the product. If you would prefer not to have this data sent please go see </span> and <span class="text-sky-700">How to Disable Crash Reporting</span> to learn how to disable it.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  <!--License Section Ends-->

  <!--Footer Section Starts-->

    <section area="footer-section" class="py-4 text-white text-sm">
      <footer class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between max-w-6xl mx-auto sm: flex-col">
        <div>
          <ul class="flex flex-row gap-4">
            <li>Hello from Seattle</li>
            <li> Follow @code</li>
            <li class="bg-white px-1 text-black font-semibold ">Star</li>
            <li class="bg-white px-1 text-black font-semibold -ml-3">143,060</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="flex gap-4 items-center">
            <li>Support</li>
            <li>Privacy</li>
            <li>Terms of Use</li>
            <li>License</li>
            <li class="flex flex-col items-center">
              <div class="flex gap-1 mb-2">
                <img src="./images/microsoft.png" alt="" class="h-6 mt-2">
                <p class="text-sm mt-2">Microsoft</p>
              </div>
              <div class="flex">
                <img src="/images/copyright.png" alt="" class="h-2.5">
                <p class="-mt-1 ml-1 text-xs">2023 Microsoft</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </section>
```

Comment: @Sufiyan ahmed its working well on the screen above then 728 after that it's not

Answer (score 0):

you must have added some extra margin or padding in the code which is extending a specific section, try to find that extra margin or padding

Comment: @PeterKrebs Dear  the whole project is being made using TALWIND so the classes which are being used here in css only and i have written ther a lot of CSS ....

Comment: The idea is to post a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you don't post the whole project, just the part you have trouble with. Use the `<>` button in StackOverflow to post a runnable snippet, where you can add tailwind [should work through the CDN](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn).

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, I think this question is different to answer as you need an example that is easier to understand to make it more reproducible. So I would have added a comment to the question trying to improve it, rather than answering something that might work